# Azure Storage Copy From Blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services, azure-media-services

I am having an issue converting the Console app described here .[Copying an existing blob into a media services asset](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-copying-existing-blob/) to run on mobile app service

I have everything like for like refernces wise and code wise but have the following issue

```
// Display the size of the source blob.
Console.WriteLine(sourceBlob.Properties.Length);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Copy blob '{0}' to '{1}'", sourceBlob.Uri, destinationBlob.Uri));

// The line below gives the following error:
destinationBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + signature));
```

> Blockquote
>   'ICloudBlob' does not contain a definition for 'StartCopyFromBlob' and no extension method 'StartCopyFromBlob' accepting a first argument of type 'ICloudBlob' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Is this because i am using version 7 of the storage client and the method has been removed?

If so is there a new method of combination of methods that i can use to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 3):

From the [release notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/releases), you can find:

> Blobs: Removed deprecated (Begin/End)StartCopyFromBlob(Async) APIs in favor of using (Begin/End)StartCopy(Async) APIs.

Therefore, please use [StartCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.startcopy.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) instead of StartCopyFromBlob.

Comment: But the I cloudblob interface does not have a method called Startcopy. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.aspx

Comment: It doesn't exist in ICloudBlob interface, it exists in CloudBlob base class.

Answer (score 1):

As Zhaoxing Lu said that 'ICloudBlob' does not contain a definition for 'StartCopy'. Base on your code, you could find 'StartCopy' in `CloudBlockBlob` class.

According to the tutorial you mentioned, you could modify the type of destinationBlob:

```
CloudBlockBlob destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlob.Name);
```

Instead of:

```
ICloudBlob destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlob.Name);
```

Note: `CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference` returns a `CloudBlockBlob` object.

Then you could run the following code:

```
destinationBlob.StartCopy(new Uri(sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + signature));
```